# Having Issues with Nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm

I want to download NVM package manager in linux dell pc
I tried this command `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`but this result to a timer that is never ending    [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsPfo.png)
Than i tried running this command `git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm`
This worked for me and than i tried this `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
But now i have to run `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` this command every time i am opening a terminal

I tried above all cases
So any one have any idea how can i solve this

Answer (score 1):

You need to do or you can update your shell config to load it each time shell opens.

This can be done by adding these lines to your shell config file (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc):

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Reference: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script